# Rotating device restarting textview

Tags: android, android-studio, rotation, viewmodel

Still having issues with this, have a activity with a yes or no button to answer questions.
On rotate I want the question in the text view to be the same as the one as it was rotated and not restarted. If anyone has any help, I assume my issue is with the onSaveInstanceState , or i anyone has an easy way to do this using a view Model instead that would be great.

```
public class AnotherQuestionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private TextView mTextViewCount;
        private int [] questions= {R.string.Q1,R.string.Q2,R.string.Q3,R.string.Q4,R.string.Q5};
        private int count=0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);
            mTextViewCount = findViewById(R.id.Question_text_view);
            Button buttonDecrement = findViewById(R.id.button);
            Button buttonIncrement = findViewById(R.id.button3);
            buttonDecrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    yesbutton();
                }
            });
            buttonIncrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    nobutton();
                }
            });
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                count = savedInstanceState.getInt("Questions");
                mTextViewCount.setText(questions[count]);
            }
        }
        private void yesbutton() {
            count++;
            mTextViewCount.setText(questions[count]);
        }
        private void nobutton() {
            count++;
            mTextViewCount.setText(questions[count]);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
            
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putInt("count", questions[count]);
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#03a9f4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".QuestionActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="111dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="112dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="112dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Concussion Questions"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#e1f5fe"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Question_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Question_text_view"
        android:layout_width="279dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="226dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="226dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="226dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="226dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text=""
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#e1f5fe"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="93dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Correct Answer Given?"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textColor="#e1f5fe"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Question_text_view"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="185dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="185dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="95dp"
        android:background="@drawable/yes_button"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Yes"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Question_text_view" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="185dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="185dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="95dp"
        android:background="@drawable/no_button"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="No"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Question_text_view" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="101dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/diagnose_button"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Diagnose"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Display preview]
[image: Actual emulator view]

Current landscape xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#03a9f4"
    tools:context=".QuestionActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Concussion Questions"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#e1f5fe"
        android:textSize="22sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="139dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Correct Answer Given?"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textColor="#e1f5fe"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout19"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Question_text_view"
        android:layout_width="279dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:background="#3f51b5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#e1f5fe"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout19"
        android:layout_width="854dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="157dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        style="buttonBarStyle"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="250dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar"
            android:background="@drawable/yes_button"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Yes" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="250dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/no_button"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar"
            android:text="No"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout19" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="91dp"
        android:background="@drawable/diagnose_button"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Diagnose"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should use sharedprefrences for saving the stuff on rotate

Comment: How do I do that, apologies?

Comment: Wait actually I am ovethinking stuff add  `<activity name= ".YourActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>` to your manifest this will let the framework andele the screen rotation so it always stays the same no matter oriantation

Answer (score 0):

Answer and explanation

add

```
<activity name= ".YourActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

in Manifest file

It does not work by default because , when you change the orientation onCreate will be called again and it redraws your view.

If you write this parameter no need to handle in Activity , the framework will take care of rest of things. It will retain the state of the screen or layout if orientation is changed.

Try your layout something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#03a9f4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".QuestionActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Correct Answer Given?"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textColor="#e1f5fe"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout19"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout19"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="111dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="112dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="112dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Concussion Questions"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#e1f5fe"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Question_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="226dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="226dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="226dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="226dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text=""
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#e1f5fe"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="185dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="185dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="95dp"
            android:background="@drawable/no_button"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="No" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="185dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="185dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="95dp"
            android:background="@drawable/yes_button"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Yes" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="101dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/diagnose_button"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Diagnose"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This did work but my buttons text view change when the screen is rotated to landscape but this did not handle it the text view is displayed in the middle of all the buttons so is a mess, any idea for this?!

Comment: Yeah add a seprate layout xml for landscape so make a copy of the current layout file and in the xml change  "android:orientation=vertical" to horizontal, and then edit the layout so the layout looks good it will then automatically use the landscape layout whe screen rotate

Comment: I had done that already though.  Could it be possibly because I am using a constraint layout?

Comment: Post your XML code and screen shot of how you want it to look

Comment: @Chris I edited my answer for you with xml, that will work better you are going to have to tweak margins, apdding and that stuff , 2 tips of advice, I see this is a test app, But your naming convetions for your buttons,layouts are button1 , button2 etc, give each thier own unique name its gonna get confusing if the app gets bigger, and wrap certain parts in linear layouts inside the constaints like I have for you,

Comment: Like the 2 buttons that are horizontal next to each other wrap them in a horizontal linear layout so then they are always in line with each other, and this linear wrapping method I do also makes the app reasonably scalable

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Ok still have an issue now when I run my emulator it doesn't jump to the landscape layout just seems to stretch out the portrait one. In my design panel I can click orientation and it displays the correct one but when I run the emulator still have an issue.

Comment: check the aspect ratio of the emulator and layout, remeber diffrent aspect ratios need diffrent layout files normal, long, landscape, long landscape

Comment: @Chris , Easier way to make a layout, for one, right click the layout folder -> New -> Layout resource file, a popup window will appear, make the name the same as your current activity , then in on the left there will be avaailable qualifiers,  select orientation and select landscape, it will then make the dedicated landscape layout]

Answer (score 0):

To me it seem's that the problem is this: in `onSaveInstanceState()` you are putting the variable `count` into the `Bundle outstate` using the key "count", but in `onCreate()` you are trying to retrieve it by using the key " Questions".

Try changing "Questions" to "count".